# Flutter Support, Android Emulator Close Unexpectedly

Tags: flutter

please i really need support with flutter, in android studio, I have installed but virtual device is not starting, it shows android emulator close unexpectedly.

so i try to uninstall and reinstall the HAXM but it won't uninstall please I  need support, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to try run emulator using CMD just type

```
*path to SDK*\emulator\emulator -avd AVD_NAME -port 5554
```

it Will show logs in CMD